# How to change disassemply's path?

Tags: c#, debugging, assembly, compiler-errors, disassembly

As [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/no-source-available?view=vs-2019) suggests in order to find the source file I go to call stack -- right click on the member -- view disassembly and see that the path there just doesn't exist. How to change it to the right one?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If VS fails to load the source file, you should be asked for the correct path (a window opens). Just locate the path where you have the files stored.

Comment: @PMF It opens but the thing is it wants App.cs which doesn't exist at all! I can't choose any other file. App.cs is from an old deleted project. In this one there is another .cs with a different name. Please, let me know how to fix it!

Comment: If you don't have the original source file anymore, it is obviously not possible to display it. You can look at the disassembly or (with appropriate tools) at decompilled C#, but you can't display the source if you don't have it anymore.

Comment: @PMF got you but the thing is I don't need it anymore. I've got a new one .cs with new code. Is there a way to change the path?

Comment: No, the debugger shows the path to where the file was when the current executable was built. You can overwrite this (as described above), but the file still needs to be the same. If you want to use the new file, you should compile and run that one.

Comment: If you go to Debug->Options->General in Visual Studio, you have a setting that says "Source file must match exactly". If you disable this, you might use a newer source file as well, but depending on what the changes are, this might become very confusing.

Comment: @PMF unfortunatelly, it didn't change anything, same issue shows up this time without letting me choose a new source file. Is this it? Nothing can be done?

Comment: You still can't go back to the source file now? The path in the disassembly display will probably not change, but you might be able to step trough withhin the source file

Comment: @PMF it doesn't step through, it just breaks and doesn't go further if i press next step.

Comment: That's now hard to follow from a distance. It could be because the files don't match (the debugger may show a wrong line) or because you have some other problem, too.